# Will the new Unity desktop be programmed in Qt?

Tags: unity, qt

Will the desktop version of Unity, scheduled to appear in 11.04, be programmed using Qt?  I ask this in relation to Matt Zimmerman's [blog posting](http://mdzlog.alcor.net/2010/10/20/ubuntu-and-qt/) of several days ago, where he intimated that Qt was the more pragmatic choice for an SDK to get coders more involved.  As a corollary, it would make sense if the whole desktop were in Qt, which would also make it possible to do a lot more beautiful effects, and make a more visually engrossing desktop experience.  In any event, please elaborate on the future role of Qt in the Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: http://mdzlog.alcor.net/2010/10/20/ubuntu-and-qt/

Answer (score 21):

Unity is built using some GNOME technologies like GTK and gmenu, and some other technologies that are not officially part of GNOME, such as [Compiz](http://www.compiz.org/), [Zeitgeist](https://launchpad.net/zeitgeist), Software Center, and other bits from the [Ayatana project](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ayatana).

However for people who use older hardware or have driver problems the [Unity 2D interface](http://bfiller.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/unity-2d/) will be available in 11.04 and is programmed in Qt.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you also read up on the future of GTK+ 3.x, Clutter, and related technologies. Using Qt as the basis of the Ubuntu desktop will not automatically make the desktop any easier to use, any "prettier", any "cooler" or any more stable. Furthermore, it would be more useful to forge ahead on a path of greater cross-toolkit standards (ref: freedesktop.org) and greater interoperability, not on consolidating everything into Qt.

Answer (score 1):

At UDS Mark Shuttleworth mentioned, that one of the things that must be done until Unity will be ready to use, is to make it compatible with qt, so that these two could cooperate.

Comment: It already is, if you mean menus/appindicators etc. Those are the main features that are needed between GTK+ and QT, and both are implemented.

Comment: Yes, in that context I meant that Qt applications should have access to all of Unity's services like indicators, notifications, panel menu and launcher quicklists. That's the case, broadly speaking, already and will definitely be true for 11.04 too.